# What does ~ mean in Java?

Tags: java, android, bitwise-operators, ones-complement

I found a new symbol in a Java project and want to know what does it mean?

```
systemUiVisibility & ~View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
```

What does `~` mean in this context?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The unary bitwise complement operator** `"~"` inverts a bit pattern; it can be applied to any of the integral types, making every `"0"` a `"1"` and every `"1"` a `"0"`.

---

For example, a byte contains 8 bits; applying this operator to a value whose bit pattern is `"00000000"` would change its pattern to `"11111111"`.

---

More information is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) and [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_bitwise_operators_examples.htm).